# blocking queue implementation in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, queue

In Java, there is a class called ArrayBlockingQueue as part of its concurrent package. It is a thread-safe class where you can add and remove items from the queue without worrying about thread-safety. This class has a `put` method which allows you to put items in queue. And a `take` method removes items from the queue. Two great things about `put` and `take` is there is no need of a synchronized keyword for synchronization against thread interleaving, and `take` patiently waits until something is added to the queue, rather than throwing an exception if nothing is in it.

I try to implement something similar in ruby, but the issue is `queue.pop` seems to block even when items are added to the queue (at least for one of the queues), as shown below:

```
require 'redis'
require 'date'

def log_debug(str)
  debug_str = "#{DateTime.now}  #{str}"
    puts debug_str
end

class EmailsmsResponder
  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
  end

  # add to queue
  def produce(channel, msg)
    @queue << {channel: channel, msg: msg}
    puts "queue size: #{@queue.size}"
  end

  # take from queue
  def consume
    loop do
      log_debug "Whats going on??"
      sleep(1)
        if !@queue.empty?
          item = @queue.pop
          log_debug "removing channel #{item[:channel]} and msg #{item[:msg]} from email-sms thread from queue"
        end
    end
  end
end

class SidekiqResponder

  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
  end

  def produce(channel, msg)
    @queue << {channel: channel, msg: msg}
    puts "queue size: #{@queue.size}"
  end

  def consume
    loop do
      log_debug "Whats going on??"
      sleep(1)
      if !@queue.empty?
        value = @queue.pop
        log_debug "removing channel #{item[:channel]} and msg #{item[:msg]} from sidekiq thread from queue"
      end
    end
  end
end

class RedisResponder
  def initialize(host,port)
    @host = host
    @port = port
    @email_sms = EmailsmsResponder.new
    @sidekiq = SidekiqResponder.new
    # timeout so we wait for messages forever
    @redis = Redis.new(:host => @host, :port => @port, :timeout => 0)
  end

  def start_producers
    thread = Thread.new do
      @redis.subscribe('juggernaut') do |on|
        # message block fired for new messages
        on.message do |channel, msg|
          log_debug "New message"
          @email_sms.produce(channel, msg)
          @sidekiq.produce(channel, msg)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def start_consumers
    thread = Thread.new do
      @email_sms.consume
      @sidekiq.consume
    end
  end
end

responder = RedisResponder.new('127.0.0.1', 6379)
responder.start_producers.join(responder.start_consumers.join)
```

While one queue seems to be working properly, the other queue never retrieves anything:

```
$ ruby redis-client4.rb
2014-07-22T14:53:24-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:25-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:25-04:00  New message
queue size: 1
queue size: 1
2014-07-22T14:53:26-04:00  removing channel juggernaut and msg {"channels":["/reports/6561/new"],"data":"New reports for unit 6561"} from email-sms thread from queue
2014-07-22T14:53:26-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:27-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:28-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:28-04:00  New message
queue size: 1
queue size: 2
2014-07-22T14:53:29-04:00  removing channel juggernaut and msg {"channels":["/reports/6561/new"],"data":"New reports for unit 6561"} from email-sms thread from queue
2014-07-22T14:53:29-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:30-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:31-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:31-04:00  New message
queue size: 1
queue size: 3
2014-07-22T14:53:32-04:00  removing channel juggernaut and msg {"channels":["/reports/6561/new"],"data":"New reports for unit 6561"} from email-sms thread from queue
2014-07-22T14:53:32-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:33-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:34-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:34-04:00  New message
queue size: 1
queue size: 4
2014-07-22T14:53:35-04:00  removing channel juggernaut and msg {"channels":["/reports/6561/new"],"data":"New reports for unit 6561"} from email-sms thread from queue
2014-07-22T14:53:35-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:36-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:37-04:00  Whats going on??
2014-07-22T14:53:37-04:00  New message
queue size: 1
queue size: 5
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to implement something similar in ruby, but the issue is
>   queue.pop seems to block even when items are added to the queue

That's easy to disprove:

```
require 'thread'

q  = Queue.new
q << 'hello'

x = q.pop
puts x

x = q.pop

--output:--
hello

deadlock detected (fatal)
```

> What might I be doing wrong?

Start deleting code and simplifying things to pinpoint where the problem occurs.  The fact that you have two classes that are exactly the same means you haven't even begun to simplify.

Then there is this:

```
  def consume
    loop do
      log_debug "Whats going on??"
      sleep(1)
      value = queue.pop
      log_debug "removing channel: #{channel} msg: #{msg} of sidekiq thread from queue"
    end
  end

 ***Error in `consume': undefined local variable or method `queue'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the code below. I didn't like the fact I had to use 4 threads just to get it working, so if anyone has a more nice solution I would be glad to recommend their solution. But this seems to be working for now:

```
require 'redis'
require 'date'

def log_debug(str)
  debug_str = "#{DateTime.now}  #{str}"
    puts debug_str
end

class EmailsmsResponder
  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
  end

  # add to queue
  def produce(channel, msg)
    @queue << {channel: channel, msg: msg}
    puts "queue size: #{@queue.size}"
  end

  # take from queue
  def consume
    loop do
      log_debug "Whats going on??"
      sleep(1)
        if !@queue.empty?
          item = @queue.pop
          log_debug "removing channel #{item[:channel]} and msg #{item[:msg]} from email-sms thread from queue"
        end
    end
  end
end

class SidekiqResponder

  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
  end

  def produce(channel, msg)
    @queue << {channel: channel, msg: msg}
    puts "queue size: #{@queue.size}"
  end

  def consume
    loop do
      log_debug "Whats going on??"
      sleep(1)
      if !@queue.empty?
        item = @queue.pop
        log_debug "removing channel #{item[:channel]} and msg #{item[:msg]} from sidekiq thread from queue"
      end
    end
  end
end

class RedisResponder
  def initialize(host,port)
    @host = host
    @port = port
    @email_sms = EmailsmsResponder.new
    @sidekiq = SidekiqResponder.new
    # timeout so we wait for messages forever
    @redis = Redis.new(:host => @host, :port => @port, :timeout => 0)
  end

  def start_producers
    thread = Thread.new do
      @redis.subscribe('juggernaut') do |on|
        # message block fired for new messages
        on.message do |channel, msg|
          log_debug "New message"
          @email_sms.produce(channel, msg)
          @sidekiq.produce(channel, msg)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def start_consumers
    thread = Thread.new do
      t1 = Thread.new { @email_sms.consume }
      t2 = Thread.new { @sidekiq.consume }
      t1.join(t2.join)
    end
  end
end

responder = RedisResponder.new('127.0.0.1', 6379)
responder.start_producers.join(responder.start_consumers.join)
```

Comment: Why are you creating consumer threads inside of another thread? Why haven't you worked through a simple example using a jobs Queue and a pool of workers executing the jobs and putting the results into a results Queue before trying to tackle this?